# how to switch website database to local computers of users visitors

Tags: mongodb, couchdb

I always asked my self how can I build website where users can download database and share with each other. Like torrents or something like that.

So user comes to website and he can download all database and website from our server or from each other and have it offline and they could update it again even if our server is down, then they can share with each others. So on their desktops of mobile phones.

I think skype did something like this two users that did chat they have both copy of that chat log, so if one loose it the other have it still and it can be sync.

So if anyone can give me some idea how to do it or maybe there is something like this that makes programming easier... like sharing databases (mysql, couchdb, mongodb etc.), and then I could program it to get the database offline on their computers.

And how wikileaks did it their info it is all over the place

Comment: It is not normally considered a good thing to make a database downlaodable especially if you intend to sync it back upto your website when it comes back online after downtime due to the risk of malicious data and other exploits. You have also gotta consider allowing other users to potentially download data about others on your site (which is illegal without consent in most countries). I mean with Skype it was simpler because the two people had their data mixed and it was koind of co-owned so sharing between the two parties is natural but this might not be.

Comment: how wikileaks did it, it is all over the servers and it can't be down

Comment: I think they more like create redundancy within their network within many providers to accomodate one provider taking them down, they don't distribute their database to everyone of their users otherwise people could just as easily take out information (governments would love it) and then reupload and mess up wikileaks entirely.

Comment: upload is very dangerous, but lets say only download and keep database to their computer and they can read it offline...just update their local database...what software could be good to use it on all operating systems even mobiles

Comment: Presuming you don't allow any user information to be downloaded with that database, in mongodb, I would do this using PHP. Just create a script that will do a hot backup of a collection is send it down via the browser. You could maybe add a torrent protocol to the file so people can actually dl it through torrent but either way the best and only sure way to do this would be to create the resulting database files yourself, don't let any automated tool do it for you.

Comment: ok that is clear just with php generating the database that they can get, but then what should be good solution to give them to read all of that database offline...like develop some browser that they install on their OS and view at like online. maybe there is something like rhodes for mobile where I can develop one version for windows, mac and linux (this one maybe not)

Comment: I wouldn't force them to install software, instead I worry about the distribution now, so the file would just be a straight db file that they can import, i.e. in MongoDB a .bson file or a .csv file, let the end user worry about reading the file in their preferred program, don't hem them in, due to the type of user who will use this, they will mostly be techy individuals who will have their own programs. Though you could provide a base program I guess for those that dont have their own program.

Answer (score 0):

I would setup a cron to dump relevant MongoDB collections as CSV or JSON files to a file that's accessible to outside users. For example, here's a cron that runs every 15-minutes and exports a "users" collection inside of "mydatabase":

```
*/15 * * * * mongoexport --csv -h localhost:27017 -d mydatabase -c users -f name,email,age -o /path/to/public/users.csv
```

So then users could download the "users.csv." Of course, you wouldn't do this for sensitive information, right?

Answer (score 0):

Offline mode is a great feature for a website, but 'sharing' a database typically isn't the best way to do it, since you never know which copy of the data will be up to date, who made changes that may conflict, etc.

One option is to still use a centralized database, and queue up changes that users make to their own data, to be replayed on the server. This isn't foolproof, as there can still be data conflicts, and users can easily roll over changes. You'll want to check if there are newer revisions, who modified the item last, etc.